# kura - remote installation of deployment package via Mqtt fails

Tags: eclipse, osgi, mqtt, kura

I am having trouble installing a deployment package remotely, following are the metrics I send on the request topic - `$EDC/amir-kura/test-client/DEPLOY-V2/EXEC/download`

```
job.id=12345678910L
dp.uri=file:/home/amir/Downloads/org.eclipse.kura.example.hello_osgi/resources/dp/hello_osgi.dp
dp.name=hello_osgi
dp.version=1.0.0
dp.download.protocol=HTTPS
dp.install.system.update=false
```

The package gets downloaded successfully as I get the following reply on the `Notify` topic-`$EDC/amir-kura/new-client/DEPLOY-V2/NOTIFY/test-client/download`

```
{dp.download.size=0, 
dp.download.progress=100, 
dp.download.status=COMPLETED, 
job.id=12345678910, 
client.id=test-client}
```

But, the installation fails. Following is my kura console-

```
15:06:07,357 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  CloudServiceImpl:440  - Message arrived on topic: $EDC/amir-kura/test-client/DEPLOY-V2/EXEC/download
15:06:07,382 [pool-2-thread-2] INFO  CloudDeploymentHandlerV2:459  - About to download and install package at URL file:/home/amir/Downloads/org.eclipse.kura.example.hello_osgi/resources/dp/hello_osgi.dp
15:06:07,382 [pool-2-thread-2] INFO  CloudDeploymentHandlerV2:468  - Downloading package from URL: file:/home/amir/Downloads/org.eclipse.kura.example.hello_osgi/resources/dp/hello_osgi.dp
15:06:07,387 [pool-12-thread-1] INFO  DataServiceImpl:441  - Storing message on topic :$EDC/#account-name/new-client/DEPLOY-V2/NOTIFY/test-client/download, priority: 1
15:06:07,389 [pool-12-thread-1] INFO  DataServiceImpl:444  - Stored message on topic :$EDC/#account-name/new-client/DEPLOY-V2/NOTIFY/test-client/download, priority: 1
15:06:07,402 [DataServiceImpl:Submit] INFO  MqttDataTransport:512  - Publishing message on topic: $EDC/amir-kura/new-client/DEPLOY-V2/NOTIFY/test-client/download with QoS: 1
15:06:07,403 [pool-12-thread-1] INFO  DownloadImpl:131  - Ready to install
15:06:07,405 [pool-2-thread-2] INFO  DataServiceImpl:441  - Storing message on topic :$EDC/#account-name/new-client/DEPLOY-V2/REPLY/REQUEST_M2UIS65D0O7DFILVRH9QF80QKE, priority: 1
15:06:07,423 [pool-2-thread-2] INFO  DataServiceImpl:444  - Stored message on topic :$EDC/#account-name/new-client/DEPLOY-V2/REPLY/REQUEST_M2UIS65D0O7DFILVRH9QF80QKE, priority: 1
15:06:07,430 [DataServiceImpl:Submit] INFO  MqttDataTransport:512  - Publishing message on topic: $EDC/amir-kura/new-client/DEPLOY-V2/REPLY/REQUEST_M2UIS65D0O7DFILVRH9QF80QKE with QoS: 0
!SESSION 2017-05-16 14:51:45.651 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_121
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_IN
Command-line arguments:  -dev file:/home/amir/eclipse/workspaces/kura/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/Kura_Emulator_Linux/dev.properties -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -consoleLog -console

!ENTRY org.apache.felix.deploymentadmin 4 0 2017-05-16 15:06:07.499
!MESSAGE Stream does not contain a valid deployment package: missing manifest!
15:06:07,500 [pool-12-thread-1] INFO  InstallImpl:135  - Install failed!
15:06:07,509 [pool-12-thread-1] INFO  DataServiceImpl:441  - Storing message on topic :$EDC/#account-name/new-client/DEPLOY-V2/NOTIFY/test-client/install, priority: 1
15:06:07,535 [pool-12-thread-1] INFO  DataServiceImpl:444  - Stored message on topic :$EDC/#account-name/new-client/DEPLOY-V2/NOTIFY/test-client/install, priority: 1
15:06:07,550 [DataServiceImpl:Submit] INFO  MqttDataTransport:512  - Publishing message on topic: $EDC/amir-kura/new-client/DEPLOY-V2/NOTIFY/test-client/install with QoS: 1
15:06:07,684 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  DataServiceImpl:376  - Confirmed message ID: 1348 to store
15:06:07,935 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  DataServiceImpl:376  - Confirmed message ID: 1350 to store
```

According to the error I am sending an invalid deployment package, as it lacks `Manifest`, but I have created the `.dp` file as mentioned in the [Hello World Example](http://eclipse.github.io/kura/dev/hello-example.html).

How do I solve this ? Noone else seems to have encountered this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adding a second answer after @Amir comment. The other answer does not address the actual issue but may be of help in some other cases.

I think that the problem lies in the metrics sent to `DEPLOY-V2` cloudlet.

```
dp.uri=file:/home/amir/Downloads/org.eclipse.kura.example.hello_osgi/resources/dp/hello_osgi.dp
dp.download.protocol=HTTPS
```

Also in the notification there's this indication:

```
dp.download.size=0
```

The URI says it's a FILE on the local filesystem, but the protocol says to use HTTPS.

If you look at [DEPLOY-V2 documentation](https://eclipse.github.io/kura/ref/mqtt-namespace.html#deploy-v2) you will read that

> Kura 1.4.0 introduces a new version of the DEPLOY application named “DEPLOY-V2”. The main feature introduced is related to a different approach for package distribution: **instead of receiving the package inside a MQTT message, the device receives only a download request with all the information needed to perform an independent download via HTTP**.
>    **dp.uri** (String). Mandatory. Represents the URI of the deployment package.
>    **dp.download.protocol** (String) Mandatory. Specifies the protocol to be used to download the bundles/shell scripts. Must be set to HTTP or HTTPS.

You need to provide a valid HTTP URL to download the DP from.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things to be aware of when building a Deployment Package.

1. Manifest **must be** the first entry in the DP file (which is simply a ZIP file)
2. Order of included bundles matters, they **must be** included in the DP in the same order as they are declared in the Manifest

## Manifest as first entry

The MANIFEST.MF file is included in the `META-INF/` directory. By ZIP standard you may add an entry in the file to create the directory, and a second entry with the file. This is **not** supported in DP format, so you must add directly the file with full path as *very first entry* in the resulting DP file.

For example, using `maven-antrun-plugin` to package the DP you can use `filesonly="true"` attribute on a `<jar>` command:

```
<jar destfile="${basedir}/../you.final.dp_1.0.0.dp"
     manifest="${project.build.directory}/dp_stage/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"
     includes="" filesonly="true">
    <filelist dir="${project.build.directory}/dp_stage/" files="${sortedFiles}"/>
</jar>
```

## Order of bundles

If your Deployment Package contains more than one bundle, they **must** be included in the same order as the Manifest. You can use alphabetical order, which is predictable and works well :-)
Copy your JARs in a folder and add them to the DP in a sorted fashion. Using the same `maven-antrun-plugin`:

```
<copy file="${basedir}/../project/target/first.bundle_1.0.0.jar"
      todir="${project.build.directory}/dp_stage/bundles/" />

<copy file="${basedir}/../project2/target/second.bundle_1.0.0.jar"
      todir="${project.build.directory}/dp_stage/bundles/" />

<!-- Files MUST be included in the jar in the same order as they are declared in the DP MANIFEST.
    I used alphabetical order. -->
<!-- https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html -->
<local name="sortedFiles"/>
<pathconvert property="sortedFiles" pathsep="${line.separator}">
    <sort>
        <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/dp_stage/" includes="bundles/*"/>
    </sort>
</pathconvert>
```

---

I have a personal [project](https://github.com/darugnaa/kura-web-log/) on github which does exactly this, have a look for reference.
[POM which calls maven-antrun-plugin](https://github.com/darugnaa/kura-web-log/blob/master/distrib/pom.xml)
[Ant task to build DP](https://github.com/darugnaa/kura-web-log/blob/master/distrib/build_dp.xml)

Comment: A closer look revealed that the problem is in downloading the deployment package, not in the installation. When I send a download request a `.dp` file is supposed to be downloaded to the `/tmp` directory from the source `URI`, this file somehow is not getting downloaded properly as the file which gets downloaded is of `0 bytes`. When I paste the `.dp` file from my workspace and then send an install request the `.dp` gets installed successfully. So, how do I solve the download problem ?

Comment: @Amir I added a second answer. This looks like some bug of Kura, because it reports success when it obviously does not succeed.